# How to select all data in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to select all data or select with conditional in table `random` but I can't find any guide in MongoDB in Python to do this.

And I can't show all data was select.

Here my code:

```
def mongoSelectStatement(result_queue):
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
    db = client.random

    cursor = db.random.find({"gia_tri": "0.5748676522161966"})
    # cursor = db.random.find()
    inserted_documents_count = cursor.count()

    for document in cursor:
        result_queue.put(document)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite comprehensive documentation for mongodb. For python (Pymongo) here is the URL: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/

Note: Consider the version you are running. Since the latest version has new features and functions.

To verify pymongo version you are using execute the following:

```
import pymongo
pymongo.version
```

Now. Regarding the select query you asked for. As far as I can tell the code you presented is fine. Here is the select structure in mongodb.

First off it is called **find()**.

In pymongo; if you want to select specific rows( **not** really **rows** in mongodb they are called documents. I am saying rows to make it easy to understand. I am assuming you are comparing mongodb to SQL); alright so If you want to select specific document from the table (called **collection** in mongodb) use the following structure (I will use **random** as collection name; also assuming that the random table has the following attributes: **age:10, type:ninja, class:black, level:1903**):

`db.random.find({ "age":"10"  })` This will return all documents that have age 10 in them.

you could add more conditions simply by separating with **commas**

`db.random.find({ "age":"10", "type":"ninja"  })` This will select all data with age 10 and type ninja.

if you want to get all data just leave empty as:

```
db.random.find({})
```

Now the previous examples display everything (age, type, class, level and _id).  If you want to display **specific** attributes say only the age you will have to add another argument to find called **projection** eg: (1 is show, 0 is do not show):

```
{'age':1}
```

Note here that this returns **age** as well as **_id**. _id is always returned by default. You have to explicitly tell it not to returning it as:

```
db.random.find({ "age":"10", "name":"ninja"  },  {"age":1, "_id":0} )
```

I hope that could get you started.
Take a look at the documentation is very thorough.